# how to adjust the rendering sequence of table rows in mysql after an update was made

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a social Page widget for a CMS I am building. In the MySQL table I have a column called `sequence` which allows the user to select the rendering sequence of the linked icons in the widget.

My goal is to adjust each of the other sequence numbers in the various other rows of the table after and update is made to a specific row.

Example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

If and update is made to change 3 to 1:

I need:

> 3 to change to 1 - 1 to change to 2 - 2 to change to 3 - 4 to remain 4 - 5 to remain 5

I have tried numerous different math formulas each returning the list jumbled with repeated numbers and such. The code I am presenting returns the following:

> 3 becomes 1 - 1 become 2 - 2 becomes 3 - 4 becomes 5 - 5 remains 5

Here is the code:

```
$social_page_id = $_POST['social_page_id']; 
    $network_name = $_POST['network_name']; 
    $page_url = $_POST['page_url']; 
    $title_text = $_POST['title_text']; 
    $icon_source = $_POST['icon_source'];
    $glyph_code = $_POST['glyph_code']; 
    $val = $_POST['glyph_color'];if($val[0] == '#'){$val = $val;}else{$val = '#'.$val;} $glyph_color = $val; 
    $sequence = $_POST['sequence'];

    # get existing sequence number
    $selectqup = $db->prepare("SELECT sequence FROM social_pages WHERE social_page_id>=".$social_page_id.""); $selectqup->execute();
    while($row = $selectqup->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $xs = $row['sequence'];
    }   

    # while loop to adjust other page sequences
    if($sequence != $xs){       
        $selectqup = $db->prepare("SELECT social_page_id, sequence FROM social_pages WHERE social_page_id>= 1"); $selectqup->execute(); 
        while($row = $selectqup->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $this_id = $row['social_page_id']; 
            $os = $row['sequence'];

            if($os < $xs){
                if($os <= ($sequence - 1)){$ns = $os;}
                elseif($os >= $sequence){$ns = $os + 1;}
            }
            if($os > $xs){
                if($os <= $sequence){$ns = $os - 1;}                
                elseif($os >= ($sequence + 1)){$ns = $os;}          
            }

            $updateq=$db->prepare("update social_pages set sequence=:AAA where social_page_id=$this_id"); 
            $updateq->bindParam(':AAA',$ns,PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $updateq->execute();
        }   
    }   


            $updateq=$db->prepare("update social_pages set
                    social_page_id=:social_page_id, 
                    network_name=:network_name, 
                    page_url=:page_url, 
                    title_text=:title_text, 
                    icon_source=:icon_source,
                    glyph_code=:glyph_code, 
                    glyph_color=:glyph_color, 
                    sequence=:sequence

                    where social_page_id=$social_page_id");         

                    $updateq->bindParam(':social_page_id',$social_page_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $updateq->bindParam(':network_name',$network_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $updateq->bindParam(':page_url',$page_url,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $updateq->bindParam(':title_text',$title_text,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $updateq->bindParam(':icon_source',$icon_source,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $updateq->bindParam(':glyph_code',$glyph_code,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $updateq->bindParam(':glyph_color',$glyph_color,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $updateq->bindParam(':sequence',$sequence,PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $updateq->execute();
```

Comment: It sounds like this code does exactly what you want?

Comment: (If not, and assuming you want a feature to "promote to top" then renumber that item as `0` and then use a select to read all the items in their sequence order, and then use a `for()` loop to renumber them starting from 1).

Comment: The goal is to simply adjust the other rows according to the update. Somehow the math is not accounting for the updated one. Things work fine until that one is reached. The reason why it always is correct is because of the update occurring after the math in the while loop

Comment: Alright. Can you try my suggested algorithm? A `for()` loop seems much simpler than the way you have it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @halfer for your assistance. I wasn't quite sure where to go with the for(). I found the problem in the pdo queries... it was not in the math. I answered the question below with the new code in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was so sure the issue was in the math... it wasn't... the math is correct. I went to the beginning of the script and ran var dumps. Apparently the pdo query in getting the existing sequence number for item being updated was not working correctly. I replaced it with this:

```
# get existing sequence number  
    $id = $social_page_id;
    $selectqup = $db->prepare("SELECT sequence FROM social_pages WHERE social_page_id>=:THEID LIMIT 1");    
    $selectqup->bindValue(':THEID',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT); $selectqup->execute();
```

And then to be sure I replaced the pdo in the while loop with:

```
$updateq=$db->prepare("update social_pages set sequence=:AAA where social_page_id=:THEID"); 
            $updateq->bindParam(':AAA',$ns,PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $updateq->bindParam(':THEID',$this_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $updateq->execute();
```

The script works fine now.

Thanks to all who assisted. The entire new code is here:

```
$social_page_id = $_POST['social_page_id']; 
$network_name = $_POST['network_name']; 
$page_url = $_POST['page_url']; 
$title_text = $_POST['title_text']; 
$icon_source = $_POST['icon_source'];
$glyph_code = $_POST['glyph_code']; 
$val = $_POST['glyph_color'];if($val[0] == '#'){$val = $val;}else{$val = '#'.$val;} $glyph_color = $val; 
$sequence = $_POST['sequence'];

# get existing sequence number  
$id = $social_page_id;
$selectqup = $db->prepare("SELECT sequence FROM social_pages WHERE social_page_id>=:THEID LIMIT 1");    
$selectqup->bindValue(':THEID',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT); $selectqup->execute();

while($row = $selectqup->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){$xs = $row['sequence'];}  

# while loop to adjust other page sequences
if($sequence != $xs){       
    $selectqup = $db->prepare("SELECT social_page_id, network_name, sequence FROM social_pages WHERE social_page_id>= 1"); $selectqup->execute();   
    while($row = $selectqup->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 

    $this_id = $row['social_page_id']; 
    $net_name = $row['network_name'];
    $os = $row['sequence'];

        if($os < $xs){
        $type = 'os less xs';
            if($os <= ($sequence - 1)){$ns = $os;}
            elseif($os >= $sequence){$ns = ($os + 1);}
            else{}
        }
        elseif($os > $xs){
        $type = 'os more xs';
            if($os <= $sequence){$ns = ($os - 1);}              
            elseif($os >= ($sequence + 1)){$ns = $os;}          
        }

        $updateq=$db->prepare("update social_pages set sequence=:AAA where social_page_id=:THEID"); 
        $updateq->bindParam(':AAA',$ns,PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $updateq->bindParam(':THEID',$this_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $updateq->execute();            
    }   
}   


        $updateq=$db->prepare("update social_pages set
                social_page_id=:social_page_id, 
                network_name=:network_name, 
                page_url=:page_url, 
                title_text=:title_text, 
                icon_source=:icon_source,
                glyph_code=:glyph_code, 
                glyph_color=:glyph_color, 
                sequence=:sequence

                where social_page_id=$social_page_id");         

                $updateq->bindParam(':social_page_id',$social_page_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $updateq->bindParam(':network_name',$network_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $updateq->bindParam(':page_url',$page_url,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $updateq->bindParam(':title_text',$title_text,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $updateq->bindParam(':icon_source',$icon_source,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $updateq->bindParam(':glyph_code',$glyph_code,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $updateq->bindParam(':glyph_color',$glyph_color,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $updateq->bindParam(':sequence',$sequence,PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $updateq->execute();
```